# Getting error-"Name error:name false is not defined " even when False is not used in the code

Tags: python, docker

```
Error-

Traceback(most recent call last)
"hidden"=false
Name error:name false is not defined
```

I am using docker to containerise my python script.The image got build successfully but when I am running the container,I am getting  error.I have not specified "False" anywhere in the code but then also I am getting the error.Unable to understand this.need some help on it

Comment: What's the code?

Comment: Please construct your question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have not used "False" anywhere in the code

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your Code I can only guess, but for it seems like you are writing `false` instead of `False`. Python is case sensitive. And the  correct spelling is with a camel F